# How to check when a protractor.ElementFinder is null

Tags: typescript, protractor

I have an implementation similar to the following:

```
const arrayOfElements: protractor.ElementArrayFinder = $$('firstName');
returnElementMatchingCriteria.then( do something with the element..


public returnElementMatchingCriteria(criteria: string): Promise<protractor.ElementFinder> {
    arrayOfElements.each(element)
         if (element.text() === criteria) {
             return element
```

If there are no matching elements, then the function is evaluated as null.  How can I check whether the returned value is null, before proceeding with the next line?

I have tried to use something similar to if (returnedValue === null) but a string literal cannot be applied to type ElementFinder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to use [`filter()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) instead of `each()` and use [`count()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) to check the results:

```
var arrayOfElements = $$('firstName');
var result = arrayOfElements.filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText().then(function (text) { 
        return text === criteria;
    });
});
expect(result.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);

// do something with result - e.g. result.first() to get the first matching element
```

In case there are no matching elements the `result.count()` would evaluate to 0.